# Determine the interval of the result of a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

For the integral
$$
\int_1^2 \frac {3^x + 2}{3^{2x} + 3^x} dx
$$
choose the interval of its result: $(-\infty, 0], (0, \frac 12], (\frac 12, 1], (1, 3], (3, \infty)$. According to the author of this task you do not have to compute the integral itself to determine the interval. I have managed to compute the integral but I am unsure how to determine the interval without computing it. How can I do that?

Comment: For one, if the function integrand is denoted $\;f\;$ , then we have that $\;0\le f\le1\;$ , so that integral is between zero and the integral od $\;1\;$ on $\;[0,1]\;$ , which is $\;1\;$ ...again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x) = \frac {3^x + 2}{3^{2x} + 3^x} $$
$$ f'(x) = -\dfrac{\ln\left(3\right)\left(3^{2x}+4{\cdot}3^x+2\right)}{3^x\left(3^x+1\right)^2} < 0 ~\forall  ~ x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Thus, $f(x)$ is a decreasing function.
$$ \implies f(1) >f(x) > f(2)$$
$$\implies \dfrac{5}{12} >f(x) > \dfrac{11}{90}$$
$$\implies \int_1^2 \dfrac{5}{12} dx > \int_1^2 f(x) dx > \int_1^2 \dfrac{11}{90} dx$$
$$\implies \dfrac{5}{12} > \int_1^2 f(x) dx > \dfrac{11}{90}$$
$$ \therefore I \in \left(0, \dfrac12\right] $$

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that someone else had already posted an answer before I submitted mine. It was unanswered when I started writing my answer.

Comment: Now worries yours is more detailed than mine:)

Answer (score 3):

Since the function $f(x)=\frac{x+2}{x^2+x}$ is decreasing for all  $x\ge 1$ we have $$g(x)=\frac{3^x+2}{3^{2x}+3^x} \implies g(x) \le g(1) =5/12 \space \forall x\in[1,3]$$ thus $$0\le \int_1^2\frac{3^x+2}{3^{2x}+3^x}\le \frac{5}{12}(2-1)< \frac{1}{2}$$